# how to close the colorbox window using the popup window in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have started using jQuery colorbox to open the popup window from the parent window.

Now what I am trying to do is- Suppose a popup window is open and there is some link in that popup window and If I try to click that link, it should open that link in a new external window and the original popup window should get closed.

Below is my parent window code that will open the popup window-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Colorbox Examples</title>
        <style>
            body{font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif; padding:0 10px;}
            a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}
            h2{font-size:13px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\rj\Downloads\colorbox-master\example4\colorbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\rj\Downloads\colorbox-master\jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Other Content Types</h2>
        <p><a class='iframe' href="popup_window_url">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>

        </body>
</html>
```

And below is my popup window code which will have one link that I need to open in a new external window by closing the original popup window-

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Apply</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function getUrlParameters() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
        function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}
var id = getUrlParameters()["ID"];    
var title = getUrlParameters()["Title"];    
id = unescape(id);
title = unescape(title);

var myJScript = document.createElement('script');

myJScript.setAttribute('type', 'Apply');
myJScript.setAttribute('data-companyId', '40');
myJScript.setAttribute('data-jobTitle', id );
myJScript.setAttribute('data-email', 'admin@domain.net');

document.body.appendChild(myJScript); 
</script>
<hr>

<input name="Apply Online" type="button" id="Apply Online" value="Apply Online" ONCLICK="window.location.href='some_url'">

</body>
</html>
```

Now how to close the popup window in this case after clicking Apply Online link button and Apply Online link should get opened in a new external window? I hope the question should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `colorbox.close()` on click for links inside your colorbox div.

```
$("apply_online").click(function() {
    colorbox.close();
    window.open('some_url');
});
```

BTW **`id`** cannot have spaces... so this is wrong:

```
<input name="Apply Online" type="button" id="Apply Online" value="Apply Online" ONCLICK="window.location.href='some_url'">
```

Needs to be:

```
<input name="Apply Online" type="button" id="apply_online" value="Apply Online" ONCLICK="window.location.href='some_url'">
```

Comment: so apply_online is the id here and I need to replace it with Apply Online..? And as soon as I click on the Apply Online link, it will open the new external window right? and colorbox will be close.. Am I right?

Comment: Yup, apply_online should be the ID - no spaces are allowed. Check my answer I updated it. Basically when you click on the button, call the function to close colorbox, and then open the link.

Comment: And also ONCLICK command will be there in the input tag here or not?

Comment: Nah don't use that if you are using the separate jquery Click function.